# How can I determine when a user logs in to a workstation using a certificate as opposed to a username and password?

Tags: windows, certificate, active-directory, authentication, smartcard

We have rolled out smart cards and Yubikeys to most of our users. We need to collect metrics on the usage of these MFA devices. Right now we have custom code that runs on the client that does an OK job of collecting this data, but I want to move the data collection server side. This info has to be on the domain controllers, and I have found a few events that get me some of the information, but not all.

This page here has been helpful: https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/federated-authentication-service/config-manage/troubleshoot-logon.html#vda-security-log

How could I collect the following information:

1. The user that logged in
2. What machine they logged into
3. The device they used/the certificate used

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Active Directory. The chain of trust is the Yubikey has a unique private key (which can not be extracted) and certificate with matching public key, issued by a CA trusted by the AD admins. They would then enter the certificate into AD with mapping of what certificate(s) a user is allowed to use. Windows uses the PKINIT Kerberos protocol between the client and the DCs. The DC can log the certificate, user and client machine. You would know which Yubikey was used. The additional assumption is the Yubikey and PIN have not been shared or stolen.

The same logic applies to web server smart card authentication.